# How to project the actual model geomtry through a camera view into a texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, scripting, camera

I have a building model too detailed for my purposes. I basically have been taking screenshots of the model and using the screenshot as a texture for each side of the building. Is there a less hacky way to accomplish something like this? Is there a way to set up 4 cameras around the building and grab all my screenshot/textures at once?

Comment: if you mean projecting various aspects of a high-resolution model to textures on a low-resolution model, is this not [baking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/baking.html), one way or another?

Comment: Kind of but I've never heard anyone use baking to describe what I'm trying to do

Comment: The Hi-res model exists as geometry in your scene? You just want, say, its color, as a texture on a Lo-res model?

Comment: Not quite. I also want a projection of some of the geometry

Comment: You mean, as if a view of the object is projected on to the surface, from the same angle as the view?

Comment: Like imagine there is a complex object with a bunch of overlapping pipes on the outside of a wall, then you take a picture of that object with a head-on direct angle. Then you turn that picture into a texture for a flat wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following Python script. Copy and paste the script into the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) within the *Scripting Tab*. Make sure to change this line within the script:

```
scene.render.filepath = f'/path/to/your/file/{image_name}.png'
```

to the path where you want to save the generated image files. Select the object from which you want to obtain screenshots from each side and click *Run Script*.

```
import bpy
from math import radians

c = bpy.context
scene = c.scene
scene.frame_current = 1
scene.frame_set(1)
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'

def render_camera_at(x,y,z,image_name):
    scene.camera.rotation_euler = radians(x), radians(y), radians(z)
    bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()
    scene.render.filepath = f'/path/to/your/file/{image_name}.png' # change this line, example f'C:/Users/somebody/Desktop/{image_name}.png'
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True)

render_camera_at(90,0,0,"front")
render_camera_at(-90,180,0,"back")
render_camera_at(90,0,-90,"left")
render_camera_at(90,0,90,"right")
render_camera_at(0,0,0,"top")
```

This will automatically position your active camera to each side and render it. It will generate images with names *front.png, back.png, left.png, right.png, top.png*. Make sure there is a camera in the scene. It doesn't matter where or how it is positioned, the script will take care of that. And also make sure you have selected the house object before running the script.

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly! Only thing I can't figure out is how to change the quality of the resulting images. I've looked here https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.html#bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings and changed the `compression` and `quality` properties of `scene.render.image_settings`, but there was no change to the resulting output images (although the script took longer to complete). Not a huge deal as I mainly needed this script for prototyping anyway, but it'd be nice to know how to improve the output quality just in case.

Comment: +1 Very nice... just wondering, strictly, does the camera need to be orthographic?

Comment: I just used the exact code except for the filepath, so whatever the default camera is I guess

Comment: nice thank you! double check if `type(scene.render.image_settings)` really outputs `bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings` then `100` should be maximum lossless compression` else it is a bug. can you share the PNG file output you got and explain what exactly in that file you think makes it not lossless?