# Fast way to place and render from many cameras automatically

Tags: animation, camera, gltf

I have a scene in Blender where I want to place about 100 different cameras around an object and render an image from each one of them.  Then I want to export all cameras in a `.gltf` file. The images are then required for a NeRF (Neuronal Radiance Field). My thoughts are that the cameras are arranged hemispherically around the object in Blender. Does anyone have an idea how this can best be implemented?

One consideration was to place all the cameras manually, but that's too much effort. Is it possible to do this with an animation or via scripting?

thanks in advance

Comment: maybe this can help give u an idea https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283642/142292

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie thank you for the link. The thing is that I also need all the different camera poses later in the .gltf file and it seems that this script uses just one camera :/

Comment: its easy to create multiple cameras with python. google is your friend :)

Comment: Are the locations/orientations of the cameras systematic, in some way?  Without knowing how .. it's almost impossible to answer this question .. please expand on that to help us out. Maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/130404/35559 would be of interest.

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you for your link. I will check it today. The images are needed for rendering a NeRF (Neuronal Radiance Field).  One option would be, for example, that the cameras are arranged in a kind of hemisphere around the object. I am going to update my question regarding this point. Thanks a lot!